# Java code stuck in infinitely repeating while loop

Tags: java

I have some code that shuffles a deck of cards by assigning randomly chosen cards from a 2D array `cards` into an ArrayList `deck`, but when I run the code it gets stuck in an infinite loop.

It was working fine at first but seemed to randomly stop working with little change to the code.

`cards` is a 13 x 4 array with a different card in each position.

```
ArrayList<String> deck = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)  {
            int v = 0;
            int s = 0;
            Boolean notInDeck = false;
            while (!notInDeck) {
                v = rand.nextInt(13);
                s = rand.nextInt(4);
                if (!deck.contains(cards[v][s])) {
                    notInDeck = true;
                    deck.add(cards[v][s]);
                }
            }
        }
```

I tried adding outputs at different points to try and track what was happening

```
ArrayList<String> deck = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)  {
            System.out.println("1");
            int v = 0;
            int s = 0;
            Boolean notInDeck = false;
            while (!notInDeck) {
                System.out.println("2");
                v = rand.nextInt(13);
                s = rand.nextInt(4);
                if (!deck.contains(cards[v][s])) {
                    System.out.println("3");
                    notInDeck = true;
                    deck.add(cards[v][s]);
                }
                System.out.println("4");
            }
            System.out.println("5");
        }
        System.out.println("6");
```

There are no error messages.

The output is fine for the first bunch of run-throughs, being `1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5`, but ends up infinitely repeating `2 4 2 4 2 4`...

It should be like `1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5` then maybe sometimes `1 2 4 2 3 4 5` when it repeats a set of random numbers.

Here is my code for the `cards` 2D array.

```
String[][] cards = new String[13][4];

        String suit = " ";
        String value = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)  {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)  {
                if (j == 0) {
                    suit = "C";
                } else if (j == 1) {
                    suit = "H";
                } else if (j == 2) {
                    suit = "S";
                } else if (j == 3) {
                    suit = "D";
                }
                if (i == 0) {
                    value = "A";
                } else if (i == 10) {
                    value = "J";
                } else if (i == 11) {
                    value = "Q";
                } else if (i == 12) {
                    value = "K";
                } else {
                    value = Integer.toString(i+1);
                }
                cards[i][j] = value;
            }
        }
```

Edit:
I realised the issue was with this line

```
cards[i][j] = value;
```

It should be

```
cards[i][j] = value + " " + suit;
```

Comment: That is not how you create a shuffled deck. You need to create a full deck, ordered and then actually shuffle that deck.

Comment: But doing it like this should work fine and it was. I was just wondering why it's not working.

Comment: To add onto @luk2302 's comment, it is possible with this code to never complete the shuffling if the random ints never generate a certain number. To shuffle a deck, you should instead loop through the array and swap each element with an element at a randomly generated row and column index.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that

Comment: Any idea why this way has just stopped working though?

Comment: @TheCardyMan Either in some way it's not programmed to get every card or just random bad luck, since you're using randoms to generate a known integer

Comment: You should really take advantage of using objects too and maybe create a `Deck` class that contains `Card` objects and you can create a fully new deck with just `Deck deck = new Deck()` and shuffle with `deck.shuffle()`.  Makes life way easier.

Comment: ok I think I found the problem. I was missing the adding the suit part of creating the array. I don't know why it what like that because it was fine before.

Comment: @TheCaryMan Yeah I noticed same time as you, seems to be because they are all the same value repeated 4 times in the matrix so it repeats forever.  Adding the suit differentiates them and stops the loop.

Answer (score 2):

You are making your life harder.

In real life, you are not taking gazillion of cards and you are not randomly picking cards until you complete full 52 cards deck. In fact, you start with 52 cards and you suffle them. Do the same here

1. Create collection of 52 cards
2. Shuffle that collection (eg. with Collections.shuffle)

While this is simply linear operation, your solution is indeterministic.

Comment: Yes, I probably will do this thank you. The reason I was doing it the other way is that I didn't know how to make a 2D ArrayList, but I suppose that doesn't matter as I don't need to organise the cards into suits and values or be able to reference them.

Comment: You dont haave to have 2d list. Just flat 52 elements

Comment: Yes I realise that now.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't run indefinitely unless you are having an unlucky day or have initialized cards array with wrong values.

So, this is what happening. Since you are using a random guess to put a card into the deck, with each attempt it's harder and harder for random generator to find, so to say, a card that was not placed in the deck yet. At the of the day you will have more and more attempts to place last cards correctly. The number of those attempts could reach hundreds and even thousands.

I have added a couple of lines to your code and visualized the problem on [Ideone](https://ideone.com/TwFurp).

```
ArrayList<String> deck = new ArrayList<String>();

HashMap<Integer, Integer> guesses = new HashMap<>();

for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
  int guess = 0;

  int v = 0;
  int s = 0;
  Boolean notInDeck = false;

  while (!notInDeck) {
    v = rand.nextInt(13);
    s = rand.nextInt(4);
    guess++;
    if (!deck.contains(cards[v][s])) {
      notInDeck = true;
      deck.add(cards[v][s]);
      guesses.put(i, guess++);
    }
  }

}

for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry: guesses.entrySet()) {
  System.out.printf("%2s : %s\n", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
```

If you execute the code several times, you will clearly see the pattern—the number of guesses grows significantly at the end.

Comment: This is what I thought was happening at first and yes I do see the issue with my method but I'm sure this isn't what's happening as the output of numbers continues for minutes and repeats hundreds of thousands of times.

Comment: Then, provide your array of cards, please.

Comment: Suits are not assigned, hence the indefinite execution. Change `cards[i][j] = value;` to `cards[i][j] = suit + value;`.

Comment: Yes I noticed that but it was fine before. I don't know where that went. thanks